# how does sortWithinPartitions sort?

Tags: apache-spark, orc, columnsorting, snappy

After applying sortWithinPartitions to a df and writing the output to a table I'm getting a result I'm not sure how to interpret.

```
df
.select($"type", $"id", $"time")
.sortWithinPartitions($"type", $"id", $"time")
```

result file looks somewhat like

```
1 a 5
2 b 1
1 a 6
2 b 2
1 a 7
2 b 3
1 a 8
2 b 4
```

It's not actually random, but neither is it sorted like I would expect it to be. Namely, first by type, then id, then time.
If I try to use a repartition before sorting, then I get the result I want. But for some reason the files weight 5 times more(100gb vs 20gb).

I'm writing to a hive orc table with compresssion set to snappy.

Does anyone know why it's sorted like this and why a repartition gets the right order, but a larger size?

Using spark 2.2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation of [sortWithinPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sortWithinPartitions-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) states

> Returns a new Dataset with each partition sorted by the given expressions

The easiest way to think of this function is to imagine a fourth column (the partition id) that is used as primary sorting criterion. The function [spark_partition_id()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#spark_partition_id) prints the partition.

For example if you have just one large partition (something that you as a Spark user would never do!), `sortWithinPartitions` works as a normal sort:

```scala
df.repartition(1)
  .sortWithinPartitions("type","id","time")
  .withColumn("partition", spark_partition_id())
  .show();
```

prints

```
+----+---+----+---------+
|type| id|time|partition|
+----+---+----+---------+
|   1|  a|   5|        0|
|   1|  a|   6|        0|
|   1|  a|   7|        0|
|   1|  a|   8|        0|
|   2|  b|   1|        0|
|   2|  b|   2|        0|
|   2|  b|   3|        0|
|   2|  b|   4|        0|
+----+---+----+---------+
```

If there are more partitions, the results are only sorted within each partition:

```scala
df.repartition(4)
  .sortWithinPartitions("type","id","time")
  .withColumn("partition", spark_partition_id())
  .show();
```

prints

```
+----+---+----+---------+
|type| id|time|partition|
+----+---+----+---------+
|   2|  b|   1|        0|
|   2|  b|   3|        0|
|   1|  a|   5|        1|
|   1|  a|   6|        1|
|   1|  a|   8|        2|
|   2|  b|   2|        2|
|   1|  a|   7|        3|
|   2|  b|   4|        3|
+----+---+----+---------+
```

Why would one use `sortWithinPartitions` instead of [sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sort-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-)? `sortWithinPartitions` does not trigger a [shuffle](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-shuffle-partitions/), as the data is only moved within the executors. `sort` however will trigger a shuffle. Therefore `sortWithinPartitions` executes faster. If the data is partitioned by a meaningful column, sorting within each partition might be enough.